# Unable to post "€" Symbol with Buffer API

Tags: php, encoding

I'm using the Buffer API with PHP and I can't figure out how to post the € symbol. I've tried without encoding, url encoded and utf8 encoded and neither of these has worked.

If I try to post: "I have 5€ in my pocket lol"
All I get is: "I have 5 in my pocket lol"

How can I post this kind of symbols? Thank you!

here's the code:

```
require_once 'class.bufferapp.php';
$buffer = new BufferPHP('1/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
$data = array('profile_ids' => array());
$data['profile_ids'][] = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';


$data['text'] = "I have 5€ in my pocket lol";
$ret = $buffer->post('updates/create', $data);
var_dump($ret);

/* Response:

object(stdClass)#2 (5) { ["updates"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (16) { ["_id"]=> string(24) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" ["client_id"]=> string(24) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" ["created_at"]=> int(1361285095) ["day"]=> string(5) "Today" ["due_at"]=> int(1361289540) ["due_time"]=> string(7) "4:59 pm" ["id"]=> string(24) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" ["profile_id"]=> string(24) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" ["profile_service"]=> string(7) "twitter" ["status"]=> string(6) "buffer" ["text"]=> string(25) "I have 5 in my pocket lol" ["text_formatted"]=> string(25) "I have 5 in my pocket lol" ["type"]=> string(4) "text" ["updated_at"]=> int(1361285095) ["user_id"]=> string(24) "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" ["via"]=> string(3) "api" } } ["buffer_percentage"]=> int(20) ["buffer_count"]=> int(2) ["success"]=> bool(true) ["message"]=> string(49) "One more tweet in your Buffer. Keep it topped up!" }
```

Comment: When you are editing or creating this file, you need to save it in UTF-8 encoding using the text editor settings... that's all you need to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It works for me with `\xE2\x82\xAc`

Hope it works for you!

Comment: -1.. you could both just configure your text editors to use UTF-8  and it will work without any hacks. When the text editor is properly configured, it will write the bytes `0xE2 0x82 0xAC` to file automatically if it contains a `€`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the sign with &#8364

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't work, I get: "I have 5&#8364 in my pocket lol"

Comment: I've tried: &#8364; &euro; &#x20AC; &#128; %E2%82%AC â¬ and none of them worked this is quite weird lol

Comment: Hmmm.. I don't have any ideas then.